# "Malo" in Motto Maelstrom

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, motto, translation-explanation

The motto for Concordia University Saint Paul (MN) reads: 
"In litteris proficere volo, malo diligere Jesum."

The CSP website, magazine (Spring 2009), and various internet sources offer these translations—some literal and some interpretive:

- I wish to be proficient in academics, but even more I wish to know Jesus.
- It is good to pursue knowledge, better to know Jesus.
- Will Prosper in Academics and Be Diligent in Christ.

And even this interesting adaptation:

- Lord, give us joy in education especially knowing the love of Christ.

I'm having a hard time fitting "malo" into this, because everything I've found or learned relates it to bad or evil. I've tried my Cassell's, and the [Latin Dictionary](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/adjective:malus).

Is there a comparative or superlative at work (or play) here, that I am not comprehending?

Any insight would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*malo* here is the first-person singular active indicative form of *malle*, which means “I prefer”. It has nothing to do with either *malus* “bad” (or, for that matter, *malum* “apple”). I believe that the verb is a contraction of *maius* “better” and *velle* “to want”.

EDIT: [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=malo) says that it's actually from *magis* "more" + *velle*.

Comment: Thank you, NRitH, for your answer. Please see disclaimer in my comment above. However, I wanted to let you know that I learned something else (beyond my momentary myopia when attempting a search this arvo) interesting from your post, namely the idea of the "contraction of maius 'better' and velle 'to want'" that I had not considered. Cheers!

Comment: I'm confused by the rollback of the edit--any particular reason you want it to stand this way?

Answer (score 8):

To add to this, there's an old mnemonic rhyme for the word *malo*:

> *Mālō*, I would rather be
>   *Mālō*, in an apple tree
>   *Mālō*, than a ship at sea
>   *Mălō*, in adversity

It's a confusingly ambiguous word! In the first line, it's a form of *mālle*, "to want"; in the second line, it's the ablative of position of *mālus*, "apple tree"; in the third line, it's the ablative of comparison of *mālus*, "upright beam, post, mast" (or "ship" by synecdoche); in the fourth line, it's the masculine ablative of *mălus*, "bad". The fourth of these is the only one that looks any different, since it has a short *ă* rather than a long *ā*.

Comment: This is wonderful!

Comment: What a fascinating word pond! Charmed I am to be /  sprouting cognitively / at sea in synecdoche / enlightened incredulity!

Comment: I just saw this, but the fourth line would actually be neuter, no? I think I remember learning this (or something like this?) way back in high school, but I had entirely forgotten it!